# Vue printing page without footer and header

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, printing

I want to know if it is possible to print content from website (component or multiple components) by Vue. I found some libraries that can do it, but I don't want to use any external libs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want to do, but it's possible with CSS to define specific layouts for printing:

```
@media print {
   header {display:none;}
   footer {display:none;}
}
```